# Shell script to separate and move landscape and portrait images

Tags: shell-script, files, images, mv

I have a directory of `jpg` images.  Is there a shell script (`bash` or `zsh` would be acceptable) that would move all landscape images into a directory, and all portrait images into another directory?

Comment: You mean landscape="width>height" and portrait="width<height", right? You don't mean landscape="hills, forests and lakes" and portrait="people posing as if for a photo".  Just checking...

Comment: @Kusalananda Now that you mention it, detecting images with hills, forests, and lakes would be an interesting problem too.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, perhaps we could use facial recognition software to determine if a photo was indeed a portrait.  But what if *the hills have eyes*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `imagemagick`'s `identify` with the `fx` special operator to compare height and width e.g. check `h/w` ratio:

```
for f in ./*.jpg
do
  r=$(identify -format '%[fx:(h/w)]' "$f")
  if (( r > 1 )) 
  then
      mv "$f" /path/to/portraits
  elif  (( r < 1 ))
  then
      mv "$f" /path/to/landscapes
  fi
done
# mv ./*.jpg /path/to/squares
```

This leaves the square images in the current directory. Uncomment the last line to move them to their own directory. Or, if you wanted to include them to either landscapes or portraits, change one of the comparison operators to either `<=` or `>=`.

Answer (score 3):

This uses the `fileinfo` utility to get an image's width and height.  If the height is greater than the width, the file is moved to the `portraits/` directory.  If not, it is moved to the `landscape/` directory.

```
for f in ./*jpg
do
    if fileinfo "$f" 2>&1 | awk '/w =/{w=$3+0; h=$6+0; if (h>w) exit; else exit 1}'
    then
        mv "$f" portraits/
    else
        mv "$f" landscape/
    fi
done
```

The file name in this loop is double-quoted where needed so that this loop is safe to use even for image file names with spaces, newlines, or other difficult characters.

On a debian-like system, `fileinfo` can be installed via:

```
apt-get install leptonica-progs
```

Other similar utilities can be used as long as the awk command is modified appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

Using `identify` from ImageMagick:

```
#! /bin/sh                                            
identify -format '%w %h %i\n' -- "$@" 2>/dev/null | \
    while read W H FN; do
        if [ $W -gt $H ]; then
            echo mv -f -- "$FN" /path/to/landscape/
        else
            echo mv -f -- "$FN" /path/to/portraits/
        fi
    done
```

This is not particularly efficient because it runs `mv` for each file, but you didn't ask for efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

(Thank you for the useful codes btw. Wouldn't have found the solution myself.)

The fx:(h/w) doesn't render things well in a bash script here. The portrait files landed in the Landscape folder.

This does work well (I use cp, copy, as I wanted to keep all the originals in the original folder. The division to Portrait or Landscape dirs is essential to resize the pictures seperately afterwards):

```
mkdir -p Portrait
mkdir -p Landscape
for f in ./*.jpg
do
  r=$(identify -format '%[fx:(h>w)]' "$f")
  if [[ r -eq 1 ]] 
  then
  echo "Copy vertical fotos to Portrait folder..."
  cp "$f" ./Portrait/
  else
  echo "Copy horizontal fotos to Landscape folder..."
  cp "$f" ./Landscape/
  fi
done
```

It's as solid as what was written in one of the first comments, combined with what was written later on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if you get an arithmetic error with any of the other solutions.

```
#/bin/zsh
mkdir -p portraits
mkdir -p landscapes
for f in ./*.jpg
do
  r=$(identify -format '%[fx:(h/w)]' "$f")
  if [[ r < 1.0 ]] 
  then
      echo "Portrait detected."
  mv "$f" ./portraits/
  elif  [[ r > 1.0 ]]
  then
  echo "Landscape detected."
      mv "$f" ./landscapes/
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you elaborate a bit on what an arithmetic error is and how this could help with that?